# What are reasons a device is not recognized?

Tags: android, eclipse

I cannot get the Eclipse SDK to recognize my Android device (a gTablet). I have spent a lot of time researching this issue, but have not found a solution. I posted a question here yesterday related to this issue and there has been no resolution. I was thinking maybe a different approach might help. Can someone please list as many reasons as possible (including reasons considered remote) why a device would not be listed in the "Android Device Chooser" screen (in other words, what are reasons the SDK won't recognize an attached device). Maybe if all possible reasons were given, I could narrow down the cause of the problem. Plus, the listing might help others in the future, even if their problem isn't exactly the same as mine. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer after trying a zillion things. All that needed to be done to fix the problem was turn to OFF 'USB debugging' and then turn it right back on. I found the idea on this page... http://www.mobileread.mobi/forums/showthread.php?t=156247 . Hope that might save someone else hours of time.

Answer (score 1):

Have you downloaded the drivers for your device? If not, i would start there.

It would also help if you told us what tablet you are using.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I cannot find any drivers for the tablet (I have looked around, but can't locate any, even on the manufacturer's site). It is a g-Tablet. My earlier post gave more specific information about my system & device, but there was no resolution, so I was thinking maybe a more general approach (e.g. "what are all possible causes") might be better. That way I could try to rule out each possible cause. If you have any thoughts on this issue or have any idea where I might be able to find a driver for the g-Tablet, I'd sure appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the drivers installed?

Check:
http://www.androidtablets.net/forum/viewsonic-gtablet-technical/5377-adb-g-tab-step-step.html

Comment: Thanks for your response. Sorry I didn't notice it down here earlier. :-( Unfortunately, the page is for Windows & I'm using a Mac. It gave me an idea to look around the Android SDK Manager. I found a Google USB Driver package,but it says it's not compatible w/Mac. I also found a Google Webdriver package & installed it, but it didn't work. I couldn't find the files mentioned on the linked page,but maybe because this is for Windows. Do you know if there's an equivalent version for Mac? It seems like things are pointing to drivers, but I don't know how to find them. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I switched the **USB cable** and it works.